# How can I display users nickname from Firebase in an array then in a TableView (For loop issue)

Tags: ios, firebase, for-loop, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing an app when I'm trying to find users by retrieving them nickname from Firebase Database during search in a search bar. I want put all my users in an array at first but I can't.

**Edit with the code working :**

```
var userTab = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "pseudo").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if (snapshot.value is NSNull) {
            print("Aucune donnée trouvée dans la base de données")
        } else {
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let userSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
                let uid = userSnap.key
                let userDict = userSnap.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                let pseudo = userDict["nickname"] as! String
                let total = snapshot.childrenCount
                print(pseudo)
                self.userTab.append(pseudo) // I change this line self.userTab = [pseudo]
                self.resultsController.tableView.reloadData() // I add this line
                print(self.userTab)

                continue // I add this line too
            }
        }
    })
        print("userTab: \(self.userTab)") // Now the array isn't empty
}
```

In the For Loop I can access the variable "pseudo" and print all users nicknames in the console, but **outside the For Loop** I can't put the pseudo variable in the array userTab. How can I do that? I really need to fill my userTab with the nickname of users and show all in a TableView then.
I already try to declare the "pseudo" variable outside the viewDidLoad() method but same issue, the array is always empty after the For Loop. What I did wrong?

**See my edit**, now all the users nickname are in the userTab array and I can search for them in the search bar and display the result in the tableView.

Comment: Before fetching data, create your table with headers. After then, add items to the array and create rows to the table simultaneously.

This can solve your problem.

Comment: I didn't put in the code in my post but I already did that. Would you want I put my full code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`observeSingleEvent` is async, it is not outside loop but in different time,
try to set breakpoints to see where it stops first

you set `self.userTab = [pseudo]` so now just reload tableview

Comment: what do you mean by stops first ?

Comment: did you try set breakpoints? in `self.userTab = [pseudo]` and in the place where you are trying to print it?

Comment: if you have 2 breakpoints you know that one of them will stop program first

Comment: I see what you mean, I didn't try breakpoint yet but my code doesn't stop, it just prints nothing in the array outside the loop. I didn't put my tableView code in the question but I can put my full code here

Comment: so set this breakpoints, your printing is done AFTER setting results in array

Comment: the first breakpoint is for: print("userTab: \(self.userTab)")

Comment: exactly, so it will always be empty

Comment: Yes you're right but do you know why this line is in first call but this line is after the For Loop?

Comment: How can I fix that ?

Comment: call for database elements is async so it is done indifferent thread so it will not block app when it is taking a long time

Comment: there is nothing to fix, everything is working, read my answer

Comment: Ok I reload tableview in the For Loop but same so I just add Continue at the end of the For Loop and it can work good, thank you for your help

Comment: if you reload right after for loop everything should work

Comment: I edit my answer, I change my way to add data in array too. Ok for your answer you help me thanks

Comment: Great, have a nice day!